# How "big" can the center of a finite perfect group be?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

A *perfect group* is a group where the derived (commutator) subgroup $G'$ of $G$ equals $G$. $G'$ measures the "non-abelian-ness" of $G$, in a sense. This suggests that "many" elements of perfect $G$ don't commute, though "many" others must commute in any finite group, given that any element of a finite group generates a cyclic subgroup.

It occurred to me that the *center* $Z(G)$ of $G$ might provide some guidance: e.g. the center (elements that commute with everything) of a perfect group must be "small", perhaps as small as trivial (e.g. the center of perfect $A_5$ is trivial). But some Googling suggests that the center of a perfect group need not be trivial (*Gr$\ddot{u}$n's lemma*: $G/Z(G)$ is centerless, but $Z(G)$ may be nontrivial). I *think* I'm interpreting this correctly, but I could be wrong!

> Question: Does $G$ being a finite perfect group say anything about the structure of $Z(G)$? In particular, is there a lower bound on its index $[G:Z(G)]$ in terms of $|G|$?

Comment: Thanks so much! Both answers as of 7/4/2015 are great (upvoted), but Derek Holt's answer gave me a bit more insight. It is truly surprising how big the center of a perfect group can be given what a perfect group represents.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are such bounds, but $|Z(G)|$ can be bigger than you might expect.

The Schur Multiplier of a $p$-group $P$ of order $p^n$ has order at most $p^{n(n-1)/2}$ (see [here](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Upper_bound_on_size_of_Schur_multiplier_for_group_of_prime_power_order_based_on_prime-base_logarithm_of_order)), which is about $|P|^{\log |P|}$. For a perfect group $G$, $Z(G)$ is a quotient of the Schur Multiplier of $G/Z(G)$, and the order of this is at most the product of the orders of the Schur Multipliers of its Sylow subgroups, so we get $|Z(G)| \le n^{\log_2 n}$, where $n = |G/Z(G)|$, which is an improvement on the bound given by mesel's answer.

Some improvements on this may be possible, but there are examples in which $|Z(G)| = n^{O(\log n)}$. Specifically, let $p \ge 5$ be prime, and let $V$ be the natural module for ${\rm SL}(2,p)$. Then there is a perfect group $G$ with $Z(G)$ elementary abelian of order $p^{n(n+1)/2}$, and $G/Z(G)$ an extension of $n$ copies of $V$ by ${\rm SL}(2,p)$. So $|G/Z(G)| = p^{2n+1}(p^2-1)/2$.

Answer (score 9):

There are two nice bounds,

Let's $|G:Z(G)|=n$ and $G=G'$

**1.)** There is a minimal generating set $S$ for  $G$ such that $|S|\leq n^2$

**2.)** For all $g\in G$, $g^n=e$.

First arguments proof comes from the idea that $[x,y]=[z_1u,z_1s]$ for $z_1,z_2\in Z(G)$. By manupulating, we will get $[x,y]=[u,s]$. Hence every commutator can be written as a commutator of elemets which is taken from left coset representator of $Z(G)$. We will get $n^2$ diffrent commutator.

Second arguments proof comes from transfer theory and it is nontrivial fact.

Comment: Could you say more about the second fact? Would you happen to know a reference for this fact?

Comment: By transfer theory, we know that the map $g\mapsto g^n$ is always a homomorphism where n is the index of the center of $G$. Clearly, the kernel contain $G'$, as it is a homomorphism from a group $G$ to an abelian group $Z(G)$. Then the result follows. You can check Isaac's Finite group Theory book (chapter 5).